# ReactJS: Render some components only on demand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using a list of 50 `Accordion`-elements (semantic ui) like this:

```
<Accordion>
    <Accordion.Title>
        <TextArea
            defaultValue={ value }
            autoHeight
        />
    </Accordion.Title>
    <Accordion.Content>
        <List>
            <List.Item>100 Items</List.Item>
        <List>
    </Accordion.Content>
</Accordion>
```

As you can see, there is a list which has 100 items for each Accordion Content.

So right now the 100 list items are rendered 50 times. But I want them to be rendered only if I open the specific Accordion. That means all 100 Accordion elements are rendered first, but no List item at all. If the user opens an Accordion, the List is rendered.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of which accordions are open in the state and use the state to conditionally render the Accordion's `List` tag.

For example if you're keeping track of your open accordions by setting/deleting keys in `this.state.openAccordions` and you're rendering an array of `accordions`:

```
return accordions.map((accordion, key) => {
    return <Accordion key={key}>
        <Accordion.Title>
            <TextArea
                defaultValue={ value }
                autoHeight
            />
        </Accordion.Title>
        <Accordion.Content>
            { /* only render <List> if Accordion is open */ }
            {(key in this.state.openAccordions) && <List>
                <List.Item>100 Items</List.Item>
            <List>}
        </Accordion.Content>
    </Accordion>
})
```